# How to have three applications side by side on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, gui, window-manager

How can I have three applications open side by side on Windows 8?
Seems like a simple thing to me but after spending an hour on Google still no answer.

I know there is a 3rd party called toolbox that lets six specific apps run side by side (six fixed apps, including Facebook, which I never use). But I want to see three apps opened side by side: MS Word, Excel and a Notepad text file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just right click on the task bar and select "Show Windows side by Side'

Comment: @ Ramhound i need 3 windows not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [feature](http://blog.laptopmag.com/windows-81-three-four-split-screen) was [added in Windows 8.1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-59-Larry-Osterman#time=19m00s). So make sure you update your Windows 8 via store to 8.1.

[image]

Comment: I upgraded. so Just drag and reside windows? So far I have been able to get more than 2 apps in one screen

Comment: I haven't upgraded to 8.1 jet, so I can't test this.